# No linux section in sdk add-ons

Tags: android, plugins, adb

So im trying to get ADB up and running. I installed Android SDK Manager and when i open tools so i can manage the add-on sites there is not a linux section so for me to follow. I need to install NOOK SDK Add-on. Is NOOK SDK located in a different directory?

Answer (score 0):

- Click Dash Home, type terminal, and open a terminal.
- Change directory to the tools directory where you unzipped the Android SDK software and type: `./android`
- Mouse over the top bar to show the Packages and Tools menus for the Android SDK Manager, and click Tools > Manage Add-on Sites:

[Source](https://nookdeveloper.zendesk.com/entries/21943338-nook-developer-start-up-guide#_Install_NOOK_SDK_Addon)

Comment: Ive done all that but there is not a Linux section there for no NOOK SDK Add-on. Where do i find the add-on for NOOK SDK?

Comment: did you follow "Complete the NOOK SDK Add-on Installation" on that page?

Comment: https://nookdeveloper.zendesk.com/entries/22167968-Ubuntu-Linux-Getting-ADB-working....This is the page im using to get adb working

Comment: you say "I need to install NOOK SDK Add-on" so that i provide the above.

Comment: you might try this page [https://nookdeveloper.zendesk.com/entries/21943338-nook-developer-start-up-guide#_Install_NOOK_SDK_Addon] Section 2.4 describes how to get the NOOK SDK. Section 2.4.1.3 is for Ubuntu Linux. Section 2.4.2 tells which URL for a specific NOOK device. Section 2.4.3 Complete NOOK Add-on Installation. As Avinash Raj mentioned above.